Make copilot key work as right-CTRL again under Linux
My new laptop features the new windows copilot key instead of the normal right CTRL key.
How to remap this key under modern Linux/Gnome/Wayland?
The key does not send one scancode but sends left-Shift + Windows key + F23 simultaneously.
I attempted to learn about Linux key mappings, but I'm unclear on how they work with three keys pressed simultaneously. Additionally, I'm uncertain which subsystem is best to modify for this purpose in 2024, particularly with a modern setup using Fedora 40, GNOME 46, and Wayland.

If you cannot reprogram the key, perhaps a tool such as ComposeKey (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) could intercept that key combo to do something else.

@Tristan, any success?

No, in seems to be a fixed list of 10 keys. Checked under Settings/Keyboard/Special Character Entry/Compose Key.
But even if I do not want the button to have any other functionality. I would like this key to be known to whole system as RIGHT_CTRL, so that any old shortcut still works (e.g.. one handed zooming in browser, with RIGHT-Ctrl and +).

I have the same problem on my new laptop which is running Linux Mint. If there were a fix for this I would be so happy.

Similar question, but for changing the Copilot button back to Ctrl (Right) in Windows: https://superuser.com/questions/1864523/restore-copilot-key-to-ctrl-right-on-windows-keyboard

With keyd I was able to remap the copilot key. Here is the relevant config.
f23+leftshift+leftmeta = overload(control, esc)


This looks very promising. Currently I only managed to map the key to one other key, e.g:
leftshift+leftmeta =t
But I am struggling to make the key work like the real control key. Currently control up and down are emitted together. But I need ctrl down alone, then I press + or - for zooming in browser and then ctrl up. Any ideas on those?
PS: I had to left out "f23+", it did not work on my fedora with keyd v2.5.0 (f33dca8).

I have zooming working but the copilot key has to be pressed every time again.
I assume that is a hardware limitation of this key, it does not wait for keyup.
[ids] * [main] #copilot emits up/down simultaneously, to only oneshot works  leftshift+leftmeta =oneshot(copilot)  [copilot] #german "+" for zooming ]=C-] #german "-" for zooming /=C-/

Not sure why f23 wouldn't work. I am using keyd v2.4.3 (5e4ef41). It didn't work for me until I used the overload. I think that takes care of the held logic. https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd/blob/393d341464fe567515e767bfae8167a38fa6fb3d/docs/keyd.scdoc#L693C1-L694C68

@Tristan I think you may want f23+leftshift+leftmeta = layer(control)

I also didn't see the f23 key (Archlinux, Thinkpad p14s Gen 5). However, remapping without it caused my WM shortcuts using Shift-Meta to break. Turns out it was reported as unknown key in dmesg, and mapping it to f23 via a udev hwdb drop-in file made things work. I needed [meta+shift] f23 = ... in my case, though.

In my case (Asus Vivobook S 14 2024 + Fedora 40), it worked perfectly with the following configuration: leftshift+leftmeta = layer(control).

Confimring kaleemsagard's configuration worked perfectly for me.
leftshift+leftmeta = layer(control)

In my case with a HP ZBook laptop, pressing the Copilot key sends a combination of left-meta + left-shift very quickly (within 2ms): press left-meta, press left-shift, release left-shift, release left-meta.
Releasing the Copilot key does nothing.
I used kmonad to remap Copilot key to a sticky right-ctrl, which seems to work fine:
(defsrc
  lmet
  lsft
  )

(deflayer base
  ;; LMETA gets pressed, this could be due to either Copilot, or a normal press.
  (around-next-timeout 2
    ;; Change to remap-copilot layer for 2ms. If it's the Copilot key,
    ;; the next LSHIFT will cause RCTRL from that layer to get pressed.
    (layer-toggle remap-copilot)
    ;; Otherwise, behave as a sticky key.
    ;; Note that you can't put LMETA alone here, as around-next-timeout
    ;; will *tap* this key instead of pressing.
    (sticky-key 500 lmet))
  ;; LSHIFT has no use here
  _
  )

(deflayer remap-copilot
  _ _ (sticky-key 500 rctl))


I'm sorry, being new I cannot comment, but the answer provided above (by Joshua), which is also the accepted answer, works very well also on my Lenovo Legion 5 Laptop.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to vote up questions and answers that you found helpful. - From Review
