Restore Copilot key to Ctrl (Right) on Windows keyboard
As noted in Make copilot key work as right-CTRL again under Linux, the new Copilot key on a Windows keyboard replaces the Ctrl (Right) key and, rather than sending a single code, sends a Win + Shift + F23 chord press. I, and I'm sure others, have no need for a dedicated Copilot key (I know how to run it when I need it) and I've become very accustomed to navigating code with the Ctrl (Right) + Cursor keys with one hand.
I know about the Microsoft PowerToys Keyboard Mapper. It's not enough to remap the key; one needs to remap the shortcut. I've tried to remap the shortcut to Ctrl (Right), but the result is still coming with a Shift press.
Has anyone been able to turn their Copilot key back to a regular Ctrl (Right) key for use in Windows 11?
